# Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA "missing" from SSMS authentication options

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio, azure-active-directory, ssms

I am trying to connect to from SSMS/VS 2022 to a database hosted on Azure. When trying to login via either application, the authentication option "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA" is not available, in fact, no Azure Active Directory options are available at all.

The options I have are below...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tya5u.png)

I have made sure "SQL server data tools" are installed.

Versions used (some info removed for brevity)
**SQL Server Management Studio**
SQL Server Management Studio                        19.2.56.2

**Visual Studio 2022**
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.8.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.8.3+34330.188
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Professional

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.8.358.6298
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

.....

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

......

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

......

**SQL Server Data Tools   17.8.119.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools**

......

Comment: Entra is Azure AD it's its new name.

Comment: Azure Active Directory is now Microsoft Entra ID, refer this link -https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/identity-access/microsoft-entra-id, thus select Microsoft  Entra MFA as your replacement for Azure Active Directory MFA in SSMS

Comment: Probably need to have Synonym created for this, in truth, with [[tag:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-entra-id]] being the new tag.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA - You are correct. I had completely missed the name change. Feel free to post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Azure Active Directory is now Microsoft Entra ID, refer this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/identity-access/microsoft-entra-id),***

[image]

Thus select Microsoft Entra MFA as your replacement for Azure Active Directory MFA in SSMS